# Using classes from parent page on a stand-alone Vue component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a stand-alone Vue component that is loaded through a script tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="/assets_bs/js/lap-form.min.js"></script>
```

The lap-form.js contains the component, of which I can add classes like such:

```
            <lap-form
                belowheading="Please fill out the form below for your FREE booklet."                    
                belowheadingstyle="font-weight:700;text-align:left;color:#005aa1;font-size:18px;"
                imageloc="assets/img/Q-A-Guide-4-768x849.png"
                imagealt="Book cover of the Q&A: Planning"
                imagestyle="width:364px;margin:auto;margin-bottom:14px;"
                buttonid="subbut"                    
                buttonclass="btn-gradient"
                buttontext="Send Now"
                fieldstyle="color:#005aa1;"
                list="4">
            </lap-form>
```

I am able to use the *style props and they work fine, and I can use the *class props, such as the buttonclass="" the only classes that work are the classes in my component.

BTW: the :class="buttonclass" is correct, as I say it works if I contain the style in the compiled component.

How am I able to access the classes on the parent page?

Comment: `How am I able to access the classes on the parent page?` Are you asking how to get the `props` of a child component from a parent?

Comment: No - I have a static page, "non Vue" that loads a single component. I want to access that page's css classes.

Comment: There really is no "parent" I have a single component on a existing static page, Vue documentation is very poor here (or I haven't found it yet). I build a single component, exporting the .js, and when I include the js file and the VUE cdn, I can place the component anywhere on the page. It is being treated like an iFrame, however in the way that there is no access to the page CSS. Only CSS that I placed in the component.

Comment: Are the styles in your component `scoped`?

Comment: YES!.... but that makes it so the component doesn't look "outside" the component??

Comment: It modifies all the classes within the component so they're not, `btn-primary` but `component_1_-btn-primary` or something to that end.

Comment: So if I scope the css, I do not have access to classes in a stylesheet loaded on the same page as the component was placed?

Comment: Well, that isn't necessarily the correct verbiage. You do have access but the classes will change, so those defined in your stylesheet will most likely not match those defined by the scoped styles. The component will only mutate the values for classes it finds matching styles in the `scoped styles` declarations. So if you give it something like `class="btn-primary btn-primary-scoped"`, then the `btn-primary` will be left alone as long as your `scoped styles` are for `btn-primary-scoped`, which it will change to `component_1_-btn-primary-scoped` for example.